mesh not moving with armature (using rigify)
I am a beginner using Blender for the first time. I have been trying for the past 2 days to get a mesh to move following an armature, but haven't succeeded yet.
I am using Rigify, and my ultimate goal is to export this model to Unity.
I have tried setting the mesh as a child of the armature using the "Armature Deform" and "Automatic Weights" options, but the mesh is not moving with the armature. The mesh is one that I downloaded from the internet. I tried with different kinds of clothing object, but it fails all the time.
Any advice or suggestions would be really appreciated. You can check out my Blender project file at the link below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XSATqLbBKmFBakbcgGDgnMiSGWzlXltB/view?usp=sharing
Thank you in advance for your help!

Your mesh appears to be just a T-shirt and has a ridiculously high number of vertices (around 677,000) so there's no way that rigify can cope with that. The armature itself also has odd extra bones in it so I'm not sure where that came from?
